# How to display "x days ago" type time using Humanize in Django template?

Tags: python, django, humanize

When I do this:

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ video.pub_date|naturaltime|capfirst }}
```

I get `2 days, 19 hours ago`

How can I get just 2 days without the hours. Basically if the video was published in less than a day ago then it should say X hours ago, then it should count in days like X days ago, then in weeks. I just don't want 1 hours 5 minutes ago or 2 days 13 minutes ago. Just the first part.

I looked at the humanize docs but couldn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Django has [a built-in template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) `timesince` that offers the same output you mentioned above. The following filter just strips the second part after the comma:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django import template
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def age(value):
    now = datetime.now()
    try:
        difference = now - value
    except:
        return value

    if difference <= timedelta(minutes=1):
        return 'just now'
    return '%(time)s ago' % {'time': timesince(value).split(', ')[0]}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `naturaltime` in modern django.

Given `now` is `17 Feb 2007 16:30:00`.

It changes `16 Feb 2007 13:31:29` to `1 day, 2 hours ago`.

```
{# some_template.html #}
{% load humanize %}
{{ past_time | naturaltime }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

Comment: This doesn't provide X days ago, only 'today', 'yesterday', etc

Comment: I'm just saying its nice to be aware of `naturaltime` built into django. Like `humanize` it computes `16 Feb 2007 13:31:29` -> `1 day, 2 hours ago.`

Answer (score 2):

You should duplicate your [django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize.py](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/ffff02b38da8/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#cl-139) to myapp.templatetags.myhumanize and modify it to your needs.  (I can't find the actual line that returns "x days, y hours ago".  Which version of django/humanize are you using?)

Comment: I would recommend against copying code and modifying it. That could break stuff from newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also now use an ExpressionWrapper or Case/When that will utilize the queryset and database to format it directly.

Example output, in combo with day/days pluralized off the top of my head:

```
overdue = ExpressionWrapper(timezone.now() - F('due_date'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
objects = Activity.objects.all().order_by('-due_date').annotate(overdue=overdue)
```