# If 'timesince' is over 24 hours then just display the day count and not the hours count

Tags: django

If a question posted is over 24 hours old then I want to limit it to show the day count and not the hours count. Obviously if under 24 hours old then show the hours count.

Currently: Asked 1 day, 18 hours ago

Optimal: Asked 1 day ago

```
{{question.created|timesince}}
```

Still fairly new to Django, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495277/3325322
There is no default filter in Django for this so it has to be adapted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at naturaltime: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

It should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I have the same problem with naturaltime. If it's published 1 week and 3 days ago, it shows 1 week and 3 days, but what I really want is to show 1 week ago. What shall I do to fix this one?