# Calculate number of days between two dates inside Django templates

Tags: python, django

I have two dates and want to show a message like "n days left before your trial end." where `n` is a number of days between two given dates. Is that better to do this inside views or is there a quick way to do it inside template itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) template tag.

Answer (score 4):

This code for HTML in Django. You can easily find the remaining days.

```
{{ to_date|timeuntil:from_date }}
```

Otherwise, you can use custom TemplateTags.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494921/how-to-display-x-days-ago-type-time-using-humanize-in-django-template)

I'd actually use the same method lazerscience uses, something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django import template
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def time_until(value):
    now = datetime.now()
    try:
        difference = value - now
    except:
        return value

    if difference <= timedelta(minutes=1):
        return 'just now'
    return '%(time)s ago' % {'time': timesince(value).split(', ')[0]}
```

Comment: It would be better to use ugettext in your function so it can be internatiomalized.

Comment: I agree, this snippet was taken from the answer I linked to and only modified to show "time until date" instead of "time since" (although it still prints out "x days ago" :P)

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML template, you can do the following:

```
{{ comments.created|timeuntil:project.created }}
```

And you get output something like this:

```
1 hour, 5 minutes
```