# Django ListView: taking a time difference in all items

Tags: django, listview, time, timezone, django-class-based-views

I'm rather new to Class Based Views, so this is probably obvious, but any tips are appreciated. I want to display "time left" for each item on a list.  That is if I have 10 objects, each should display in the template the number of days, hours, mn left until a deadline arrives.  Here's my attempt:

#### model.py

```
class Law(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(_(u'The Deadline'),)
    name = ..
    more_stuff = ..
```

#### views.py

```
class LawList(ListView):
    model = Law
    context_object_name = 'law'
    template_name = 'template.html'
```

#### template.html

```
{% for l in law %}
   <h3>{{ l.deadline }} - {{l.name }} </h3>
     {{l.more_stuff}}
{% endfor %}
```

all good up to here.  However I would like to have  `{{l.time-left}}` instead of `{{l.deadline}}`.  Is there a way for the view to calculate this and pass it to the template?

I thought of adding a `get_context_data` to the 'LawList' view, but I don't know how to do so for every item in my list.  Below is what works for a single item.

```
# views.py, below the section above
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(LawList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context['time_left'] = Law.objects.all()[0].deadline - timezone.now()
```

but I'm a little stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the [`timeuntil`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil) template tag

Comment: Never seen that one before, love discovering these little gems

Comment: thanks. that was easy :). I've also found it was a duplicate. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887897/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates-inside-django-templates) and a little more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494921/how-to-display-x-days-ago-type-time-using-humanize-in-django-template)